# How to add CDATA to a soapbody section using SAAJ

Tags: java, xml, soap, saaj

This is my java SAAJ code that am using to add the soap body. How can I add the cdata as part of the soapbody.

```
// SOAP Head
    SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
    SOAPElement soapHeadElem = header.addChildElement("xxx");

    SOAPElement soapHeadElem1 = soapHeadElem.addChildElement("xxx");
    soapHeadElem1.addTextNode("xx");


    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

    // add cdata here
```

Comment: This is how the soap looks like <!-- <soapenv:Envelope >
 <soapenv:Envelope >
   <soapenv:Header>
      <v2:RequestSOAPHeader>
         <v2:Id></v2:Id>         
        
      </v2:RequestSOAPHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <req:Msg>
    <![CDATA[<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><request>
     <Request>
     <CommandID></CommandID>
     
    </request>]]>
   </req:RequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 2):

You can create a CDATA section node with the following expression:

```
soapBody.getOwnerDocument().createCDATASection("some data")
```

You can then add that node to the SOAP body using `appendChild`.

Comment: Should I add the CDATA string in ("some data") ?

Comment: Yes, if by "CDATA string" you mean the content of the CDATA section.